# MySQL Question - I want to eliminate all text within any parenthesis

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string, replace

Just checking to see if any of you would have a solution for this – from the below text like this I want to eliminate all text within any parenthesis.

*Input* –

PAY - addition,FILES (aaaaaaaaaaaaaa/bbbbbbbbbbbs i.e. ssss,ffff – i.e. cccccc),DED (ppppppp, llllll, fffff gggg),LOSS (ddddd, hhhhhh – i.e.),F TO G ( “F” is switching to “G”)

*Output* –

PAY - addition,FILES,DED,LOSS,F TO G

Comment: What MySQL version you have?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(mytext, '\\([^)]*\\)', '')
```

This works as long as there are no nested parentheses in the expression (which is consistent with your sample data).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8970f5ffe29b59222ddb144a4458880c)**:

```
 select regexp_replace(
    'PAY - addition,FILES (aaaaaaaaaaaaaa/bbbbbbbbbbbs i.e. ssss,ffff – i.e. cccccc),DED (ppppppp, llllll, fffff gggg),LOSS (ddddd, hhhhhh – i.e.),F TO G ( “F” is switching to “G”)',
    '\\([^)]*\\)',
    ''
) val
```

```
| val                                      |
| :--------------------------------------- |
| PAY - addition,FILES ,DED ,LOSS ,F TO G  |
```

Comment: Thank you. But the mysql version that I am using is this - 5.6.28-76.1-56

Answer (score 0):

Another on for MYSQL8.0:

```
SET @input:="PAY - addition,FILES (aaaaaaaaaaaaaa/bbbbbbbbbbbs i.e. ssss,ffff – i.e. cccccc),DED (ppppppp, llllll, fffff gggg),LOSS (ddddd, hhhhhh – i.e.),F TO G ( “F” is switching to “G”)";

with recursive cte as (
    select 
        0 i, 
        @input as text
    union all
    select 
        i+1, 
        CASE WHEN instr(text,'(') >0 AND instr(text,')')>instr(text,'(') THEN REPLACE(text, substring(text,instr(text,'('),instr(text,')')-instr(text,'(')+1), '') ELSE '' END
    from cte 
    where  i<10
) select text from cte where text<>'' order by i desc limit 1;
```

output:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| text                                     |
+------------------------------------------+
| PAY - addition,FILES ,DED ,LOSS ,F TO G  |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you. But the mysql version that I am using is this - 5.6.28-76.1-56 :(